# Equivalent definitions of n-acyclic morphisms / Problem with spectral sequence

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-cohomology, spectral-sequences, etale-cohomology

I'm trying to understand section (VI.4) on smooth base change in Milne's Étale Cohomology.
He defines a morphism $g \colon Y \longrightarrow X$ to be $n$-acyclic (I only care about the case $n \geq 0$) if for any scheme $X'$ étale and of finite type over $X$ and any appropriate torsion sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ on $X'$, $H^i(X', \mathcal{F}) \longrightarrow H^i(Y', g'^*\mathcal{F})$ is bijective for all $0 \leq i \leq n$ and injective for $i=n+1$.
Here $g' \colon Y' = Y \times_X X' \longrightarrow X'$ is the base change of $g$.

It is stated that this is equivalent to the condition $(*)$ that for any $X'$ and $\mathcal{F}$ as above, the map $\mathcal{F} \longrightarrow g'_*g'^*\mathcal{F}$ is an isomorphism and $R^jg'_*(g'^*\mathcal{F}) = 0$ for $1 \leq j \leq n$.

I see why the definition implies the condition $(*)$.
However, I'm a bit confused about the other direction.
I don't have a lot of experience with spectral sequences yet, I think that's where the problem lies.

The Leray spectral sequence for $g'$ reads $H^i(X',R^jg'_*(g'^*\mathcal{F})) \Longrightarrow H^{i+j}(Y',g'^*\mathcal{F})$.
Now, using $(*)$, we find that, since the differentials on the $r$-th page have grading $(r,1-r)$, the entries at $(i,0)$ with $0 \leq i \leq n+1$ in the spectral sequence never have any non-zero arrows coming in our out of them on any page. Hence, they are already stable from the second page on, i.e. $H^i(X', \underbrace{g'_*g'^*\mathcal{F}}_{\mathcal{F}}) \cong H^i(Y',g'^*\mathcal{F})$ for $0 \leq i \leq n+1$.
But this is not what we want for $i = n+1$.

It would be nice if someone could point out what I'm misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\cF}{\mathcal F}$On the second page, out of $H^i(X',R^jg_*'(g'_*\cF))$ for $i+j=n+1$, you have two possible nonzero terms:
$$
E^{n+1,0}_2 = H^{n+1}(X',g_*'(g'_*\cF)),\quad E^{0,n+1}_2=H^{0}(X',R^{n+1}g_*'(g'_*\cF)).
$$
(I think you might be forgetting about the second one) The first one has no more nonero arrows in any pages, so like you say $E^{n+1,0}_2 \cong E^{n+1,0}_\infty$, but we don't really know what $E^{0,n+1}_\infty$ looks like, and it might be nonzero.

Once the spectral sequence has converged, what it tells us is that $H^{n+1}(Y',g'^*\cF)$ has a filtration whose graded pieces are $E^{p,q}_\infty$ for $p+q=n+1$. In this case, there are at most two nonzero graded pieces, so we just have a short exact sequence:
$$
0\to E^{n+1,0}_\infty \to H^{n+1}(Y',g'^*\cF) \to E^{0,n+1}_\infty\to 0.
$$
Since $E^{n+1,0}_\infty \cong  H^{n+1}(X',g_*'(g'^*\cF))$, there you have your injection, but since $E^{0,n+1}_\infty$ might be nonzero, it might not be surjective. The map in the spectral sequence comes from the adjunction map $\cF\to g'_*g'^*\cF$... I'm not sure what is the best way to see this. I would say that it's to see that there is a map of double complexes from the complex computing $H^i(X',g_*'(g'^*\cF))$ (seen as a double complex with just one nonzero row or column) to the one the Leray spectral sequence comes from, which will induce the map in the short exact sequence above.

---

The exact same reasoning can be repackaged with no spectral sequences, just a short exact sequence. I'm going to write it down since I personally find it helpful to understand spectral sequences when I can explain what's happening with long exact sequences.

Let $I^\bullet$ be an injective resolution of $Rg'_*(g'^*(\cF))$. Then, there is a short exact sequence
$$
0\longrightarrow \tau_{\le n}I^\bullet \longrightarrow I^\bullet \longrightarrow \tau_{> n}I^\bullet \longrightarrow 0.
$$
$\tau_{\le n}I^\bullet$ is the truncation where we replace $I^n$ by $\ker d\subseteq I^n$ and $(\tau_{\le n}I^\bullet)^i=0$ for $i>n$., and $\tau_{>n}$ is just the quotient.

Assuming that $R^ig'_*(g'^*(\cF))=0$ for $1<i\le n$ exactly means that $g'_*(g'^*(\cF))\cong \tau_{\le n}Rg'_*(g'^*(\cF))$. Also, $\tau_{>n}I^\bullet$'s cohomology is $0$ up to degree $n$. So, the short exact sequence gives us a long exact sequence taking $H^*(X',\bullet)$, which has a bunch of zeroes, so we split it into:
$$
i<n\colon \quad 0\to H^i(X',g'_*(g'^*(\cF))) \to  H^i(Y',\cF) \to 0.
$$
$$
0\to H^{n+1}(X',g'_*(g'^*(\cF))) \to  H^{n+1}(Y',\cF) \to H^{n+1}(X',\tau_{>n}Rg'_*(g'^*(\cF)))\to \cdots
$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I misunderstood what exactly it means for a spectral sequence to converge; you cleared that up for me. Also your second explanation using only exact sequences is nice.